# ActiveRecord deleting all records instead of one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I'm trying to delete user subscriptions but when ever I click on the like all subscriptions for the current_user gets removed instead of only the one that was targeted. The only thing that seems to work is raw sql

## execute sql

```
conn = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
    conn.execute(%Q{
        delete from user_subscriptions
        where user_id = #{user_id}
        and app_id = #{app_id}
})
```

## app/controllers/user_subscriptions_controller.rb

```
class UserSubscriptionsController < ApplicationController
  ...

  def destroy
    user_id = params[:user_id]
    app_id = params[:app_id]
    UserSubscription.find_by(user_id: user_id, app_id: app_id).destroy
    flash[:notice] = 'You will no longer receive notifications of new builds.'
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

## app/views/apps/_full.html.erb

```
...
<h5 class='caption-text cols-lg-12'>
  <% if @subs.include? app.id %>
    <%= link_to 'stop notifications', destroy_subscription_path(session[:user_id], app.id) %>
  <% else %>
    <%= link_to 'recieve notifications', create_subscription_path(session[:user_id], app.id) %>
  <% end %>
</h5>
```

## db/migrate

```
class CreateUserSubscriptions < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_join_table :users, :apps, table_name: 'user_subscriptions'
    execute 'ALTER TABLE user_subscriptions ADD PRIMARY KEY (user_id, app_id);'
  end
end
```

## config/routes.rb

```
get 'user_subcriptions/create/:user_id/:app_id', to: 'user_subscriptions#create', as: 'create_subscription'
get 'user_subcriptions/destroy/:user_id/:app_id', to: 'user_subscriptions#destroy', as: 'destroy_subscription'
```

## app/models/user_subscription.rb

```
class UserSubscription < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :app
end
```

## app/models/app.rb

```
class App < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :versions
  has_many :user_subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :user_subscriptions
  validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: :app_type }
```

## app/models.user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :user_subscriptions
  has_many :apps, through: :user_subscriptions
```

## app/controllers/apps_controller.rb

```
class AppsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    redirect_to root_path unless user_signed_in?
    apps = App.order(name: :asc).all
    @subs = @current_user.user_subscriptions.map(&:app_id) || []
    @android_apps = apps.select { |a| a.app_type == 'android' } unless iphone? || ipad?
    if iphone? || ipad?
      @ios_apps = apps.includes(:versions).select do |app|
        app.iphone? == iphone? && app.ipad? == ipad?
      end
    elsif android? == false
      @ios_apps = apps.includes(:versions).select do |app|
        app.ipad? || app.iphone?
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: What does it return in rails console ? `UserSubscription.find_by(user_id: User.last.id, app_id: App.last.id)`

Comment: Is your destroy action under GET verb? 00

Comment: @BroiSatse I've update with the portion of routes.rb concerning user_subscriptions

Comment: @BroiSatse, it should be DELETE verb, right?

Comment: From the manual: find_by Finds the first record matching the specified conditions. `UserSubscription.find_by(user_id: user_id, app_id: app_id).destroy` removes only a record. Fire up a rails console, create yourself a user with more than one subscription for an app, and try your code against this and look at the results. And you should not delete using get, use delete verb for this .

Comment: how does your model associations look like? do you have any :dependent => :destroy or something similar?

Comment: @Mattherick I've posted the model above. There is not relation in the user or app model relating to it.

Comment: what happens if you change your query to: UserSubscription.where(user_id: user_id, app_id: app_id).first.destroy ?

Comment: @Mattherick still the same

Comment: Can you add your user and subscription models with the association part?

Comment: @Mattherick i've posted the model as well as the app controller

Comment: I am sorry, but the associations are not complete.. you should have models: user, app and user_subscription. user: has_many user_subscriptions, has_many :apps, through => :user_subscriptions.. app: has_many user_subscriptions, has_many :users, through => user_subscriptions.. do you know what I mean? Do you have these associations already? I can´t see them in your models..

Comment: @Mattherick I did not but I have updated it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it will help. Try destroy_all

```
UserSubscription.destroy_all(user_id: user_id, app_id: app_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `DELETE` verb instead of `GET`:

*routes.rb*

```
delete 'user_subcriptions/destroy/:user_id/:app_id', to: 'user_subscriptions#destroy', as: 'destroy_subscription'
```

And anchor into this:

*app/views/apps/_full.html.erb*

```
<%= link_to 'stop notifications', destroy_subscription_path(session[:user_id], app.id), method: :delete %>
```

Comment: It still behaves the same